# spring application.yml reference list from another property

Tags: spring, spring-properties

I have property file `application-dev.yml` with content:

```
spring.profiles: dev
config.some.value:
- ELEMENT1
- ELEMENT2
```

and another `application-staging.yml` with content:

```
spring.profiles: staging
config.some.value:
- ELEMENT1
- ELEMENT2
- ELEMENT3
```

so I basically do not know size of list. When I reference this list in main `application.yml` like this:

```
some.value: ${config.some.value}
```

I get `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'value'`. How to reference it correctly?

Comment: so what do you wanna do exactly? you wanna include `staging` and `dev` in `default` application.yml?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Solution**

One way would be to use comma-separated lists in your profiles:

- application-dev.yml

```
spring.profiles: dev
config.some.value: ELEMENT1,ELEMENT2
```

- application-staging.yml

```
spring.profiles: staging
config.some.value: ELEMENT1,ELEMENT2,ELEMENT3
```

Then you should be able to access it in application.yml

```
some.value: ${config.some.value}
```

This solution doesn't require knowing list size upfront.

**Explanation**

**The reason why this is working** is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties).
Specifically:

```
YAML lists are represented as comma-separated values (useful for simple String values) and also as property keys with [index] dereferencers, for example this YAML:
servers:
    - dev.bar.com
    - foo.bar.com
Would be transformed into these properties:
servers=dev.bar.com,foo.bar.com
servers[0]=dev.bar.com
servers[1]=foo.bar.com
```

In particular this means, that if you specify comma-separated list of strings in `application.yml` and define `List<String>` as value in `@ConfigurationProperties`, spring configuration properties binder will convert that comma-separated list of string to `List<Strings>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyProfile:
SomeValues: 
    - ELEMENT1
    - ELEMENT2
     -ELEMENT3
    - ELEMENT4

---
MyProfile:   
someValues: 
    - ELEMENT1
    - ELEMENT2



@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class YAMLConfig {


    private List<String> SomeValues= new ArrayList<>();

    // standard getters and setters

}
```

To Access properties

```
  @Autowired
   private YAMLConfig myConfig;


 private List<String> SomeValues= myConfig.SomeValues();
```

This worked for me

Comment: I cannot change code. I need to do it only in .yml files.

Answer (score 0):

When using String arrays the first and only element CAN be joined by commas - the final result is the same as a list. Meaning that you can set your variable like this:

config.some.value: ELEMENT1, ELEMENT2, ELEMENT3

then, at your profile section, you can reference the configuration value as it were a normal string:

someValues: ${config.some.value}

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to create .yml file with multiple values:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  config:
    some:
      values: ELEMENT1,ELEMENT2
```

When we are using .yml files, we recommend pulling apart each word. To read values use:

```
@Value("${spring.config.some.values}")    
private String[] values;
```

I hope it helps you.