# Spring application.yml yaml list substitution?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parsing, yaml

Currently I have my application.yml and developer.yml as follows

```yaml
# application.yml file
spring.config.import: optional:developer.yml
host: ${config.host}
```

```yaml
# developer.yml file
config.host: "www.google.com"
```

The above works perfectly fine when I start my app. I am able to get the `config.host` property from my developer.yml file(since I have imported it using `spring.config.import`).

### Problem

Now I want to import a yaml **list** in a similar fashion. Assume that I have the data as follows in my developer.yml file

```yaml
# developer.yml file
config.hosts:
 - "www.google.com"
 - "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Now how do I pull this into my application.yml? I tried the below and it didn't work

```yaml
# application.yml file
spring.config.import: optional:developer.yml
hosts: ${config.hosts}
```

When I say, it didn't work I mean that the `hosts` value, instead of being injected as a List of strings, its taking the value **literally** as `"${config.hosts}"`. Meaning that substitution of yaml list from `developer.yml` into `application.yml` is not working just like how it worked for regular strings(in the first example above). Is this even possible in spring boot?

References:

- by the way, this spring blog [article](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) has some information about how they merge yaml documents(it has information about spring.config.import etc)

Comment: This is probably what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/70039090/18157 - YAML itself doesn't do any substitution, but whatever processes the YAML _may_ provide it.  See also this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5904

Comment: That is true. Hence the tag for spring boot and question starts with spring word.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```yaml
# developer.yml file
config.hosts: www.google.com, www.stackoverflow.com
```

instead of

```yaml
# developer.yml file
config.hosts:
 - "www.google.com"
 - "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Tested locally and it worked for me - `hosts` were successfully loaded as `List<String>` with two values.

Similar question: [spring application.yml reference list from another property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366636/spring-application-yml-reference-list-from-another-property)

Comment: No I want it to be yaml list itself. not comma separated string.